# Intensity of inelastic neutron scattering: analitycal expressions

Tags: resource-recommendations, neutrons, scattering-cross-section

I am currently working with experimental results of magnon spectrum (in antiferromagnet with many atoms per unit cell), which was obtained by inelastic neutron scattering method, but some spectral branches have very low intensity, and some not. I want to understand how the intensity of the specific branch depends on the combination of exchange parameters of my model. Is it possible to do without complex calculations?

And in which literature I can find examples of calculations of inelastic neutron scattering cross section on magnons or phonons?  (for instance, in case of linear chains with several atoms in the unit cell).

Comment: Can you post a link the paper which describes the data you are working with? (Or a comparable paper if your data are currently unpublished.)

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.05569v2.pdf We repeat the calculation of magnon spectrum as in this paper (experimental spectrum is shown on the picture 4 there, but we rely predominantly on our data) , using spin-wave theory. Our material contains 4 atoms per unit cell, so we expect 4 spectrum branches in each direction of the q-space, but in the direction (00l) only two branches are visible. It is not obvious why only two.

Comment: Missing branches usually suggests some degeneracy or other symmetry, but I'm a little out of my depth here.

Comment: Hello. A question for clarification: Do you ask quantum scattering theory in general and how the calculation of cross sections happen or do you ask for the specific problem your experiment needs: that is the calculation of the cross section for the specific problem? Thank you.